# What's the etiquette for improving answers that only address part of a question?

Tags: discussion, answers

The question I'm referring to: [Easy way to list node modules I have npm linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933955/easy-way-to-list-node-modules-i-have-npm-linked)

The OP asks for two different things (a local and global command). The accepted answer is a good solution for part of what they're asking. However, I also know the answer to the other part of their question.

How should I politely improve upon the answers without discounting the work of the existing answers?

My ideas so far:

1. Edit the accepted answer to add the other answer
2. Comment on the accepted answer with the other answer
3. Add a new answer with both answers to fully answer the question, but credit the user that wrote the accepted answer

Comment: Bear in mind that the question is over 7 years old just because there's an easier way to do it now doesn't mean the answer was incorrect in earlier versions. Instead, leave your own answer pointing to what version your solution works for and maybe also provide attribution to the original answer if they overlap.

Comment: This option is missing from your list of ideas: _"4. Add a new answer for the part of the question you can answer"_. That approach is explicitly encouraged in the SO documentation for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried **as a partial answer**. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on....Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful..."_

Comment: Here's the problem: *"The OP asks for two different things..."*. The problem lies in the question, not in the answer. We should keep just **one issue per question** here at SO.

Comment: Well in this case they're tightly related questions, if they were separate they may accidentally be flagged as duplicates.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No that is not the problem, and I think you are using a lawyerly interpretation to make your case. There is nothing wrong with the OP asking two closely related questions together in a single post for a single issue. Posting those two questions separately would lead to unnecessary confusion, and duplication of effort. There are many examples on SO of OPs usefully asking multiple related questions for a single issue. The criterion for closing a post that _"currently includes multiple questions in one"_ is when it does not _"focus on **one problem only**"_. (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @skomisa: But (at least according to the OP) we are *not* talking about "two closely related" questions (your interpretation) but about "two different things" (the OP's interpretation).

Comment: @JörgWMittag The OP stated _"in this case they're **tightly related** questions"_ in a comment above. Two questions within _any_ post are necessarily about _"two different things"_, but that says absolutely nothing about whether they are "closely related" or about "one problem only". For the post under discussion you don't need to be a subject matter expert to appreciate that the issues raised are about the same problem. I'll be impressed if you can make a solid case that the linked OP should have created two separate questions on SO, rather than asking them in a single post.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Without looking at the specific question you've linked to, here's some feedback for the ideas you've listed

1. No, don't do that. Edits should not change the intent of a post. Editing in another solution that's not part of the original answer definitely goes against that.
2. That's fine. Leaving a comment suggesting another solution may prompt the author to revise their answer, and if not, future readers can see your solution (assuming the comment doesn't vanish).
3. This is much better. Fully answering the question is a good idea. As you've mentioned, if you're using the contents/ideas from another answer, make sure to attribute it.

You could also post an answer containing *only* your solution so long as that's a valid solution to the question*. It's fine for a reader to have to read multiple answers to see multiple solutions to a problem.

*This assumes that the question is asking 2 closely related questions. If they're not closely related, then the question probably should not be answered until it focuses on a single question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do 2 and 3. I wanted to make sure it wasn't redundant or rude.

Comment: But 3. has a very high risk of the (misguided) necroposting reaction (in the form of downvotes). Perhaps add something about how this can be mitigated/prevented?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Fair point.  My usual approach is to say "see `[xys's answer](link)` for [this part]", often with my own TL:DR summary of it or at least the key parts, if I don't have much to add to another answer's coverage of that part.  (Especially common in CodeReview.SE questions where it's normal that there are multiple things to talk about in one question, if I want to post about an aspect that hasn't been discussed, but don't want to leave some important things unmentioned in my own answer.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Does that really happen? Of course, if the new answer doesn't add anything new, then it can get downvotes (justifiably so), but if it adds new information that's useful (in addition to citing other answers), I haven't noticed that they get downvoted.

Comment: The problem with #3 is that when you combine 2 partial answers under your own or Community account, those useful answers lose votes and rep to the now combined answer. If people cease getting rewarded for posting even partial answers, they will stop posting answers altogether. I've understood that a partial answer is better than no answer. And I'll answer the part of a Q I have knowledge about, leaving someone else to answer the rest. That's part of the reason why there's room for more than one answer, correct?

Comment: @computercarguy It's generally preferable to provide as complete an answer as possible. If an answer is a partial answer, then yes, it might get less votes over time vs a more complete answer, but I don't see that as a problem. Note that users can still upvote multiple answers if they find them useful, so partial answers can still earn reputation for its author.

Comment: FWIW popular partial answers already have the advantage of being seen by more voters because they have more upvotes. In practice, I think a more complete answer will generally only be able to compete with a less complete answer if it's determined higher quality by many, which is a good thing.

Comment: @cigien I think that it is better just to mention previous answer and add what you really want to add. Why would someone read for example accepted answer and after that see few full answers adding no value in part that is from old question (I seen this on old popular questions)? Answer is good, but it's wasting of time for reader.

Answer (score -17):

The "most correct" approach is the #3 you've listed, but this has a major issue: your better answer is going to start at 0 versus whatever score the accepted answer has, so it's probably never going to be seen and thus will never get upvoted<sup>1</sup>, so the older answer will keep being seen and keep being upvoted, thus rendering your effort to improve things completely moot.

I personally have no issues with #1. Claiming that improving someone else's answer "conflicts with their intent" is nonsensical at best - their intention was to write a good answer, you are making that answer better, how can an improvement ever conflict with what they wrote? If we take this "argument" to its farcical extreme, **any** edit to **anyone else's** content - no matter how minor - could be construed as "conflicting with their intent".

And it doesn't matter anyway, because as soon as you post something on Stack Overflow, you no longer own it<sup>2</sup>; Stack Overflow owns it, due to the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. Which means that anyone is free to edit anything to their heart's content, and doing so is encouraged when it results in improvement. The only thing that "conflicts with their intent" is really applicable to, is questions (which, again, is why the only people who should really be editing questions are the people asking said questions).

<sub><sup>1</sup> For everyone being pedantic about this statement, I'd like to introduce to you a concept called "hyperbole".

<sup>2</sup> I'm well aware this is not technically correct, but it's de facto correct.</sub>

Comment: Stack doesn't own it. They are only free to publish it under the license.

Comment: "so it's probably never going to be seen and thus will never get upvoted" - I respectfully disagree with a slam of my flat hand on the table to make it extra dramatic. I frequently find my answer in zero or one-voted answers and you can be darned skippy I upvote them with an extra firm click. I am not special at all.

Comment: @Gimby Congrats, I'm sure your single upvote is going to do everything to dislodge other answers with hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: I also added a comment. Since I did find an answer to part of the question that wasn't answered originally, I still want some reputation for it. As far as I understand reputation only goes to the OP of an edited question.

Comment: *"their intention was to write a good answer, you are making that answer better, how can an improvement ever conflict with what they wrote?"* - if we take *that* to its logical extreme, then it would be OK to edit an answer to replace it in its entirety with a better one, even if the edited answer solves the problem in a completely different way. "Conflicts with their intent" is *absolutely* applicable when editing answers, not just questions.

Comment: Regarding your other points, I have written several answers on years-old questions which have subsequently received plenty of upvotes - e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159044/12299000) (8 years later), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59025143/12299000) (6 years later), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580527/12299000) (9 years later). Also, releasing your content under a Creative Commons license still means you own the copyright to it. Granting a license is just that; in fact, the license would be legally unenforceable if you didn't retain copyright.

Comment: @kaya3 And yet none of your answers have more upvotes than the accepted one, which means your answer is far less likely to be seen, used, and upvoted. Please don't play pedantry.

Comment: You wrote that such answers *"will never get upvoted"*, which I have clearly shown to be false. If you didn't actually mean that then perhaps the problem is that you wrote it.

Comment: The fact that some other Answer on a post has 2984 upvotes doesn't mean no one ever reads a new Answer. I have no issues posting a new one and I don't expect it to get to the top.. and so what? Not everybody writes for the masses. I'm perfectly happy with the few that gets to mine. I've come to think they're the ones that I'd like to target. The ones that take their time to go through a post and learn. As for your point that the posts by @kaya3 didn't reach the top. It's likely to be become moot. Their scores seems to be rising faster relative to the time they've existed.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't own the copyright over the text of the answer, but Stack does maintain control of which version of the various CC-BY-SA-licensed answers is currently shown: the latest one, with a mechanism for other users to edit.  You can call that community "ownership" of the display space (rather than of the original post text), @Scratte.  In general I agree with Ian's core point, that editing to add new stuff to answers is sometimes the best practical option, especially when they have huge numbers of upvotes and the poster hasn't been maintaining their answer re: comments.